# Eclipse Kepler with Subclipse not picking up newly added files

Tags: eclipse, svn

my Mac is running:

- Mavericks 10.9.3
- subversion 1.8.9
- subversion-javahlbindings 1.8.9
- Eclipse Kepler SR2 with Subclipse 1.10

For some reason, when I'm working on a Project and go to Team > Commit
Subclipse will detect changes in existing files and allow me to commit, but it doesn't list *added* files.

In order to commit *added* files I have to use Team > Synchronise with Repository > Right-click on file tree > Commit

In the previous versions of svn/subclipse, added files were automatically picked up, and got committed straight from the Team > Commit dialog.

I've tried configuring Subclipse to use each oif the JavaHL and SVNKit options, but neither picks up newly added files.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In svn, new files must be explicitly added (using the `svn add` command) before they can be committed. Eclipse's Synchronize view does that for you, since it has shown you the files that need to be added and it presumes that you "approve" of the new ones. But using the Commit command directly is just calling `svn commit` without `svn add`, so the new files are not included.

Comment: With previous version-combinations of Eclipse/Svn/Subclipse, added files were automatically picked up, and got committed straight from the Team > Commit dialog.  I've been using these tools for years without needing to manually `add` new files

Comment: I just noticed you're using Subclipse instead of Subversive, so that's why my experience is different than yours. Perhaps there's a preferences setting in Subclipse that controls this behavior; seems reasonable since svn explicitly separates `add` and `commit` for specific reasons, and a tool that hides that separation should offer it as an option IMO.

Answer (score 0):

When you create new files with other editor or copy/paste in finder, some times SVN doesn't detect.

You can try refresh the Eclipse project, just click in your project select "Team -> Refresh/Cleanup" from context menu, then the files will appear in Team Synchronizing View.

Works for me.